# data.table merge for time series, with some common columns absorbed into same column

Tags: r, data.table

while i've seen many answers here for merges, I am trying to do a time series merge with data that is common to both tables.

```
#Simple example
d1 <- data.table(date = as.Date(c("2018-07-03", "2018-07-05")), x = c(1, 3), y = c(1, 2))
d2 <- data.table(date = as.Date("2018-07-04"), x = 2, z = 5)

setkey(d1, date)
setkey(d2, date)
```

I want to merge the columns together.  When I do a merge I get this:

```
xx <- merge(d1, d2, all = TRUE)
#          date x.x  y x.y  z
# 1: 2018-07-03   1  1  NA NA
# 2: 2018-07-04  NA NA   2  5
# 3: 2018-07-05   3  2  NA NA
```

I don't want duplicate x.x and x.y columns.  What I want is this:

```
xx2 <- rbind(d1,d2, fill = TRUE)[order(date)]
#          date x  y  z
# 1: 2018-07-03 1  1 NA
# 2: 2018-07-04 2 NA  5
# 3: 2018-07-05 3  2 NA
```

And I want to do this on a really large data set.  Is there a better way to do this merge, or is doing `rbind` and then sort afterwards the best way?

Comment: Please, advise what you mean by "better way"? In terms of performance? Memory consumption?

Comment: Both.  memory more so as data is large.  Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `setkey` on both `date` and `x`:

```
d1 <- data.table(date = as.Date(c("2018-07-03", "2018-07-05")), x = c(1, 3), y = c(1, 2))
d2 <- data.table(date = as.Date("2018-07-04"), x = 2, z = 5)

setkey(d1, date, x)
setkey(d2, date, x)

xx <- merge(d1, d2, all = TRUE)
> xx
         date x  y  z
1: 2018-07-03 1  1 NA
2: 2018-07-04 2 NA  5
3: 2018-07-05 3  2 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me without setting keys:

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.11.4 used
d1 <- data.table(date = as.Date(c("2018-07-03", "2018-07-05")), x = c(1, 3), y = c(1, 2))
d2 <- data.table(date = as.Date("2018-07-04"), x = 2, z = 5)
merge(d1, d2, all = TRUE)
```

> ```
>          date x  y  z
> 1: 2018-07-03 1  1 NA
> 2: 2018-07-04 2 NA  5
> 3: 2018-07-05 3  2 NA
> ```

As alternative to `rbind(d1, d2, fill = TRUE)[order(date)]` you can try

```
rbindlist(list(d1, d2), fill = TRUE)[order(date)]
```

which takes a list of data.tables as first argument.

Comment: what's favourable about  `rbindlist(list(d1, d2), fill = TRUE)[order(date)]`?  more memory efficient on large sets?